# How to test AngularJS component that use promise?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following component that I want to unit test.

```
myApp.component('myComponent', {
  controller: function($q) {
    let serviceDummy = $q((resolve, reject) => resolve(42));
    this.number = 0;
    this.$onInit = () => {
      serviceDummy.then((res) => {this.number = res; });
      serviceDummy.then(console.log);
    }
  },
  template: '<p>The answer is {{$ctrl.number}}</p>'
});
```

This is my test:

```
describe('myComponent', function() {
  var controller;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp');
  });
  beforeEach(inject(function($componentController) {
    controller = $componentController('myComponent', null);
  }));

  it('should set the number', function() {
    controller.$onInit();
    expect(controller.number).toBe(42);
  });
});
```

The component works well but the test failed.
[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndxywwbx/)

Comment: add $rootScope.$digest() before expect

Answer (score 0):

First *return* the promise created by the function under test.

```
this.$onInit = () => {
    //vvvv RETURN promise
    return serviceDummy.then((res) => {this.number = res; });
}
```

Then use then `done` function that Jasmine provides as an argument to the test handler of the `it` method:

```
  it('should set the number to 42', function testHandler(done) {
    var p = controller.$onInit();
    p.then(function() {
      expect(controller.number).toBe(42);
      done();
    });
    _rootScope.$apply();
  });
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upvjmjL3/)